# Android Cover Flow without Gallery

Tags: android, cover

I saw many examples of cover flow implements in Android, but all extends Gallery, but Gallery is deprecated over 2.2.
does anyone have new implements without Gallery?

Answer (score 0):

You can try ViewFliper or you implements it extends ViewGroup